# Where does the build happen in buildbot? can buildmaster build?

Tags: python, buildbot

So I am trying to read and work with buildbot. I am new to both python and buildbot. I have been going over the [tutorial](http://docs.buildbot.net/current/manual/index.html).  What I have learned so far is this:

Buildmaster tells the buildslave to build ( lets say boost). 
Buildslave builds it and will let the user know the build status through url. This means if I have buildmaster linux and buildslave mac(suppose) and given order to the mac to compile and run and test boost in its(mac) system: specially using command ShellCommand() It will do the build in the mac. ( AM I right ?)

My second question is does buildslave always build? Is there any chance buildmaster do the build job some time? ( I know we can create the buildslave and buildmaster in same machine) but I just wanted to know if master can also build(just curious and I know it might be unnecessary)

And lastly is buildbot 100% python ? Is it similar like saying boost is c++(or extension of c++)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, ShellCommand and most other commands run on the slave.

If you need a step to run on the master, you can use buildbot.steps.master.MasterShellCommand.

Yes, builbot itself is written entirely in python.